# Truncated fields in response on $http

Tags: angularjs, xmlhttprequest

I am sending a simple POST to a site and I want to collect the HTML content in which lies a hidden field with a VIEWSTATE value (old asp.net site).
The response when I debug the script is limited to 10168 chars... however, in the network viewer the response is complete, over 76000 chars. Does anyone know if this is an issue with the debugger or something else that limits the data received by a POST to just over 10k characters?

code:

```
$http({
  url: aURL,
  method: "GET",
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
  }).then(function (response) {
    ... do stuff here ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue revolves around Chrome debugger having a string limitation. It works fine when using Firefox.